# Generate simple JSON from Android

Tags: android, json

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray();
    jsonarray.put("Info");

    JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();
    try {

        j1.put("NAME", "NAKUL");
        j1.put("ADDRESS", "NASHIK");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsonarray.put(j1);
    Log.d("Test",jsonarray.toString());


}
```

}

It gives me output

```
12-10 14:14:59.639: D/Test(862): ["Info",{"ADDRESS":"NASHIK","NAME":"NAKUL"}]
```

but i required out put

```
["Info":{"ADDRESS":"NASHIK","NAME":"NAKUL"}]
```

that means instead of "," i required ":"

Comment: Try using the GSON library, its great when using json in Android

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a lot clearer. I suggest "Generate simple JSON from Android". There is no parsing going on.

Comment: "," this is a array element separator and this ":"  indicates that it is an object on the right side.

Comment: array is not object ..., read json documentation

Answer (score 0):

The output you say you want is not a proper array in `JSON`

`JSON` arrays only hold literals and objects, not individual key value pairs

You could try,

`jsonarray.put('info', j1)`

Which is closer to what you want, but will probably throw an error

What you really want is:

`{['Info' : {...}]}`

Test your outputs on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to make sure they're valid JSON before you try to program it.